# Displaying "tooltips" in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, gui, cross-browser

I have the following piece of code:

```
for (var i = 0, len = legend.allItems.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var item = legend.allItems[i].legendItem;

        item.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            var posLeft = 0,
            posTop = 0, 
            parentWidth = chart.chartWidth;

            var html = '<span class="legend-tooltip">' + 
                MetricsTooltips.get(chart.series[i].options.tooltipKey) + 
            '</span>';

            labelElement = chart.renderer.label(html, posLeft, posTop, 'callout', null, null, true, false, 'legend-tooltip').attr({zIndex: 10}).add();

            if(legend.group.alignOptions.align == 'center') {
                // _legendItemPos[0] returns the offset (left) for current legend item
                posLeft = legend.group.translateX + legend.allItems[i]._legendItemPos[0];
                // Subtract some "offset" as we don't want tooltips to overlap the legend
                posTop = legend.group.translateY - 30;

                // Make sure that tooltip won't overflow its parent
                if ((legend.allItems[i]._legendItemPos[0] + labelElement.width) > parentWidth) {
                    posLeft = parentWidth - labelElement.width;
                }

                labelElement.destroy();
            } else if (legend.group.alignOptions.align == 'right') {
                posTop = (legend.group.translateY + legend.allItems[i]._legendItemPos[1]);
                posLeft = (parentWidth - legend.group.alignOptions.width) - labelElement.width;

                if(legend.scrollGroup.translateY && legend.currentPage > 1) {
                    // Handle the case when legend group have too many metrics and paging appears in
                    posTop -= Math.abs(legend.scrollGroup.translateY);
                }

                labelElement.destroy();
            } else {
                // handle this if needed
            }

            labelElement = chart.renderer.label(html, posLeft, posTop, 'callout', null, null, true, false, 'legend-tooltip').css({zIndex: 10}).add();

        }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
            labelElement.destroy();
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Basically, it attach event listeners on all legend items when chart is loaded (the `for` is located inside `onload` callback), and later, when `mouseenter` event occurs, we display simple "tooltip" to the user.

It's working very well, but I'm looking for some refactoring hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My observations thus far:

- You are not actually using `mouseenter` in your code, you should as that would be the better approach
- The function inside a loop with the double `var` assignment is awkward, if you want to go functional just use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- The way you have `// handle this if needed`, the reader is not sure if that can happen. If it can happen, then the code will create 2 times `labelElement` since you did not call `labelElement.destroy();` in that `else` branch. If it cannot happen, remove the code. Also if it cannot happen, place `labelElement.destroy();` after the `if` statement
- `labelElement` seems to be a global, I hope it is created with a `var` statement elsewhere in your code
- From a naming perspective (not sure this is your naming), I have no idea what `scrollGroup` would return, and even less of an idea now that I see that that object has a method called `translateY`. You might want to re-consider carefully some of the naming.